# How deploy and run GROBID to Azure ML?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-container-service, pdf-parsing, grobid

Hello I am trying to parse a large volumes of academic papers. After some research, I came across GROBID which seems to provide best parsing of pdf documents for bibliographic data. I tried a lightweight version in my local machine which was okay.

Grobid documentation: https://grobid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Now I want use the full weight model through Azure ML.
Can someone provide me some instructions on how I can deploy such models in azure?

Also, I want to explore the results with Azure ML studio.
Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: The GROBID is not available in the Azure model catalog.

Comment: To deploy in azure ml you need a model and environment, since GROBID has inbuilt model you can not actually deploy it just using the docker image. So try using that docker image in containers and use python [sdk](https://github.com/kermitt2/grobid_client_python) to call.